# Technical term for valid but unusual?

Tags: single-word-requests, technical

This question applies primarily to coding. Is there a term that describes input that is valid but unusual?

For example: If I ask for a username, and get @##3i7&*(x]. The code should allow this, but it's not within the realm of expected, username-like inputs.

A similar real life example: going to a restaurant alone and ordering 6 of the same appetizers and a bottle of wine. This is allowed, but abnormal.

The word "strange" comes to mind, but that doesn't feel technical enough.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's wrong with "unusual"? The term makes no judgment about validity, only frequency of occurrence.

Comment: I like "unconventional" here.

Comment: +1 for *unconventional*. "Peculiar" is another possibility..

Comment: "Unusual" would as good a fit as any to the first case. "Strange" works just fine for the second.

Comment: Or *eccentric, unexpected, odd*.

Comment: Unconventional is pretty good, but I think Drew's answer of corner cases is more what I want. Thanks, though!

Comment: @##3i7&*(x] is an outlier.

Comment: 'Peripheral' as the opposite of 'central' is of a more formal (though not specifically programming) register.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger That is the answer to the question, I think. Would you consider posting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We typically refer to such cases (of atypical, bizarre, or exceptional use cases, including user input) as **corner cases**.

Comment: Labelling 'going to a restaurant alone and ordering 6 of the same appetizers and a bottle of wine' a 'corner case' could be considered even more bizarre.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Not if you are sitting in the corner. ;-) (I assumed the question, as indicated, "*applies primarily to coding*".)

Comment: Yet another case of a question with conflicting messages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: You're right. I didn't even bother with that part of the question. Maybe it should be closed as unclear.

Comment: I've just attacked the upvote. As I often find myself doing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's OK by me. And I understand the phenomenon. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Three terms immediately occur to me:
***1.*** ***Unconventional.***
***2.*** ***Atypical.***
***3.*** ***Unorthodox.***

But these are just regular words prefixed with negative modifiers.

---

I also like:
***4.*** ***Eccentric.***

And particularly applicable to programming:
***5.*** ***Idiomatic.***

> ***FYI:*** In a CLI context, I most often observe very brief, simple messages such as ***"Unexpected Argument.."*** If you're concerned about your own ambiguity and potential for being misinterpreted; try using colours and/or symbols, such as ***[ - ]*** *&* ***[ + ] ...***

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "sui generis", "unique" or "peculiar".

> - **sui generis** (adj) Sui generis is a Latin term meaning 'forming a kind by itself; in a class or group of its own : not like anything else
> - **unique** (adj) used to say that something or someone is unlike anything or anyone else
> - **peculiar** (adj)  characteristic of only one person, group, or thing :  distinctive
>
> source [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peculiar)

e.g. "a unique ball-point pen", "a most peculiar username", "his project is sui generis"